# AC storage closet cold. Rest of the apartment is warmer

Tags: hvac, air-conditioning

I live in a one bedroom apartment. It's a duplex but the other side is vacant. In the hallway there is a very small closet that holds the HVAC. I have a Goodman model capf1824a6db.

All summer the apartment has had a hard time staying cool and/or cooling down. The electric bill went up significantly. But yesterday I opened the AC closet and it is noticeably cooler in there than anywhere else in the apartment.
I changed the air filter this morning and it made no difference. I have also noticed that even though I do have cold air coming through the vents, it is not a strong airflow.

I've let the office know about it and they said they'll put me on the list. There are 6 people ahead of me on the list and only one maintenance person who can work on air conditioners or heaters. So I'd love to know what the problem is and if I can fix it myself instead of waiting for the maintenance guy to get here. (Took 9 months to get maintenance to come fix my oven. So I'm not a fan of waiting on them) oh and I'm not sure if it is possible for me to check the ducts in the attic because it's a shared attic and this side of the building doesn't have access to the attic. The other side is where you get into the attic and that side caught on fire a year ago and hasn't been fixed or even cleaned.

Comment: are the air intake (filter) blocked by furniture ? where are the air vents located ? ceiling, floor, walls

Comment: what is in the cabinet is only one part of your AC. That one is called evaporator coil. It has a Fan and cooling coil. It sucks the air from your apartment and cools it over the cold coil. The second part of the AC is outside. It has a compressor and big fan. It is very noisy. Your problem might be the coolant is low (on the outside unit), and Icing. Open a cover on the indoor unit and take look at the coil. Is it Iced ?

Comment: The vents are all on the ceiling. There's nothing blocking any of them. The air intake has nothing blocking it either. The filter for this unit is underneath the unit. In the closet the unit sits on a shelf type surface that has a hole in it that's the size of the bottom of the unit. So under the unit where the air intake is, it's hollowed out. So there nothing blocking that either. I just had coolant put in in June. And when I opened it up this morning to look at it there was no ice on any part.

Comment: And I've looked at the part outside as well to see if there's anything blocking it or crowding it and there's nothing.

Comment: You had coolant refilled ? did they test for leak ? When looking for icing make sure you see the cooling coil where the ice could be. Your symptoms indicate, Low coolant, iced coil, which would reduce air flow, unless a duct is disconnected,

Comment: Call the office and ask them what *outside* HVAC contractor they like to use. Call them up and ask them to come give you a quote to fix it. If it's something big that is beyond the ability of the landlord's handyman, the landlord would pay them *anyway*, so the landlord would likely just have them do it.  Just be warned that A/C is *not* a tenant right like running water or a working fridge. And all tenancies not in rent control areas can be terminated by the landlord at will, unless a lease is in force.

Comment: I wish that this place did use an outside handyman but they don't. The owner of this place is cheap and doesn't put any money into these buildings for anything. So the person that works on the air conditioners and heaters is someone that is only employed by this complex. I've tried feeling around the unit to see if I feel airflow coming from anywhere it shouldn't be coming from and I can't feel anything. I think there's a leak that I can't find or the ducts in the attic may be leaking or clogged.

Answer (score 2):

Check all around the AC unit for leaks, breaks in the duct work, the cool air has to be coming from somewhere. If there's a register vent in that closet, close it and see if it makes a difference. If you do fine some cool air leaking, you could seal up the opening with some foil tape or AC mastic. That's about the limit you can do to fix it if it's a rental you're living in.

Comment: What's a register vent??

Comment: @AlexisG.  it's a vent that cold air would be blowing out of.